# javascript array not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Working on a project for school and arrays are causing me a serious problem. They are returning the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: oddNumbers is not defined.
```

I did exactly what every other question on this site asked and to no avail. You can see in the ScriptManager "class" (as I am used to Java and C#) the oddNumbers and evenNumbers can't be pushed into. Please tell me whats wrong.

```
var manager = new ScriptManager();

function enterNumber() {
    var number = prompt("Enter a number");
    if (manager.addNumber(number)) {
        document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = manager.getEvenNumbers();
        document.getElementById("odd").innerHTML = manager.getOddNumbers();
        document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = manager.sum;
        document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = manager.average;
    }
}

function ScriptManager() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.oddCount = 0;
    this.evenCount = 0;
    this.sum = 0;
    this.average = 0;
    this.oddNumbers = [];
    this.evenNumbers = [];
    this.addNumber = function(number) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(number))) {
            number = parseInt(number);
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                evenNumbers.push(number);
                evenCount++;
                count++;
            } else {
                oddNumbers.push(number);
                oddCount++;
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            alert(number + " is not a valid number.");
            return false;
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < oddCount; x++) {
            sum += oddNumbers[x];
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < evenCount; x++) {
            sum += evenNumbers[x];
        }
        average = sum / count;
        return true;
    };
    this.getEvenNumbers = function() {
        var stream = "";
        var first = true;
        for (var x = 0; x < evenCount; x++) {
            if (!first) {
                stream + ", ";
            }
            stream += String.valueOf(evenNumbers[x]);
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
        }
        return stream;
    }
    this.getOddNumbers = function() {
        return "bleh";
    }
}
```

Comment: `oddNumbers` is not the same as `this.oddNumbers`.

Comment: I'm mildly embarrased

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `this.` prefix before all the object properties.

```
this.addNumber = function(number) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(number))) {
        number = parseInt(number);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            this.evenNumbers.push(number);
            this.evenCount++;
            this.count++;
        } else {
            this.oddNumbers.push(number);
            this.oddCount++;
            this.count++;
        }
    } else {
        alert(number + " is not a valid number.");
        return false;
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < oddCount; x++) {
        this.sum += this.oddNumbers[x];
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < evenCount; x++) {
        this.sum += this.evenNumbers[x];
    }
    this.average = this.sum / this.count;
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you have to use `this` in front of member variables to access them.  So:

```
oddNumbers.push(number);
```

needs to be:

```
this.oddNumbers.push(number);
```

And, similarly for all the other member variables.